# What color should be the color of unread inbox indicator?

Tags: color

Recently there was a request about changing the color of inbox unread inbox indicator to green, so it make me think:

What would be the best color or for indicator of unread inbox messages (irrelative to Stack Exchange), if I implement an interface with inbox dropdown like SE dropdown? Is red really angry color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than focussing on color,**you should focus on making it distinctive enough through contrast**. Using color alone as an indicator would make it inaccessible for people with color blindness. To quote the [W3 guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10/#gl-color)

> If color alone is used to convey information, people who cannot
>   differentiate between certain colors and users with devices that have
>   non-color or non-visual displays will not receive the information.
>   When foreground and background colors are too close to the same hue,
>   they may not provide sufficient contrast when viewed using monochrome
>   displays or by people with different types of color deficits.

You could use red or green as long as the contrast is strong enough for people to read it and make it out without relying on color.

For example, taking facebook as an example

**What a person without color blindness sees**

[image]

Here is what a person with Monochromatic vision sees

[image]

---

Taking twitter Notifications as an example

Here is what **a person without colorblindness sees**

[image]

Here is what **a person with monochromatic vision sees**

[image]

---

### So you could **potentially use any color as long as it stands out** and **the contrast is good.** Here are some examples

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 For framing this as an issue about color contrast and not about color hue. Nicael, if you are working with Adobe software they have an option under the view settings to test for protanopia and deuteranopia color blindness (dichomacy color vision is a more common  than monochromatic vision).